# what are the secure/safe onlne android emulators available?

Tags: android, android-emulator

My friend developed an android app and shared the apk with me. But I don't have android mobile and want to check of there are any online emulators available which are safe.

Please let me know.

Comment: Don't you have Android Studio?

Comment: https://www.pcloudy.com/  visit here, you will get variety of devices.

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of What is Android studio? Please share the link or info @MMG